# geoserver sld color gone in zoom out

Tags: geoserver, sld, choropleth

I badly need help... 
I have a layer served from geoserver, this layer is in polygon.. and in every polygon the color varies according to a number. so it is like a choropleth map. now my problem is the color appears only at a certain zoom level in the map. When I zoom out the color assigned to the polygon disappears, then when I zoom in again the color comes back. What should I do to retain its color even in zoom in or zoom out.

Comment: please edit your question to add details of the data source you are using and the relevant sections of the SLD. For example did you set a scale dependency? also please add screen shots of the issue if possible